# Keycloak Required actions - Terms and Conditions - issue in redirecting user back to login page (browser specific)

Tags: angular, keycloak, openid-connect, identity-management

My Keycloak version - 9.0. App front end - Angular 8

I am enabling Terms and Conditions and also setting defaults true.

[image]

I have configured the t&c page the way I wanted and it is coming up when user put their credentials. Accepting the t&c works fine, it takes user to application.

**But the issue is when user click on decline .**
Ideally it should take user back to keycloak login page but it is taking user to application page with blank page and when you do a page refresh then it takes user back to Keycloak login page.

The issue is on Safari (13.1.1) and Google Chrome (87.0.4) and it is working fine on mozila Firefox (81.0), it takes user back to login page.

Here what I get in logs:

> WARN [org.keycloak.events] (default task-3)
> type=CUSTOM_REQUIRED_ACTION_ERROR, realmId=myrealm, clientId=myclient, userId=userId,
> ipAddress=myip, error=rejected_by_user, auth_method=openid-connect,
> custom_required_action=terms_and_conditions, response_type=code,
> redirect_uri=https://domain_name/, remember_me=false,
> code_id=code_id, response_mode=fragment, username=username,
> authSessionParentId=fb55e9cf-fe78-41f7-bf04-ed4d5867d3f9,
> authSessionTabId=ecxUmJlMtoo

Anything is missing here?.. why the issue with specific browsers.. Any idea? Please help!.

**UPDATE:**
I Observed that when it works in Mozilla Firefox, It still shows the above warning in Logs.

**UPDATE 2**

I have checked on Mozilla Firefox where its working -
In Cookies I can see AUTH_SESSION_ID and KC_RESTART and when I click on decline, auth_session_id get replaced with OAuth_Token_Request_State and then again I can see AUTH_SESSION_ID and KC_RESTART are persisted when it redirects me to login page.

But this is not the case with Chrome and Safari.. when I click on decline both the cookies get vanished and it takes me to application url instead of taking back to login page on keycloak.

Answer (score 1):

Throw a try/catch around your `keycloak.init` call because `init` raises an error for this case. Inside the catch call keycloak.logout() to clear state.